# Command in a variable

Tags: bash, zsh

I am trying to run a statement where the name of the command is in a variable. For example:

```
my_command='/path/to/some/command'

$my_command -f foo -b bar -s something else
```

But the above does not work. I get errors that suggest that the shell is trying to interpret my arguments as commands.

How can I do this in Bash and Zsh?

Comment: Always post specifics. In cases like this, the exact code being used. If not possible, create a functional example. Also provide the exact error output. There are many specific errors which could fall under a broad explanation like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store a command, you can use a function:

In any Bourne-like shell but `bash`:

```
mycommand() /path/to/some/command some fixed args "$@"
mycommand other args
```

In `bash`, you need braces:

```
mycommand() { /path/to/some/command some fixed args "$@";}
```

(those braces don't hurt in other shells, so best is to use them when you need to be portable)

If you're a `csh` junkie, you could also use an `alias`.

You can use a variable as in:

```
mycommand=/path/to/some/command
```

but remember that in every shell but `zsh`, you need to quote the expansion:

```
"$mycommand" its args
```

If you want to store the command and more than it's 0th argument, you can use arrays in shells that support them (`bash` and `zsh` do)

```
mycommand=(/path/to/some/command some fixed args)
"${mycommand[@]}" some other args
```

In `zsh` you can get away with

```
$mycommand some other args
```

as long as none of the *fixed args* are empty.

Answer (score 2):

These lines below worked for me under bash:

```
mycommand=/usr/bin/find
$mycommand -type d
```

your problem maybe originating from "/path/to/some/command" and what it does or try to do. Without seeing the actual thing, it is hard to say.

Comment: Works fine for me in bash also - with or without single-quotes on the mycommand line and with it called my_command or mycommand.

Comment: That's `zsh` syntax. In `bash`, you need to quote `$mycommand`, otherwise it's subject to word splitting (for insance if IFS contains any of `/usrbinfd` characters) and filename generation (not applicable here as there's no wildcard character).